# Post request in python giving me a "could not parse request body" error? Check JSON? But it is in JSON

Tags: python, json, https, python-requests, http-post

I am getting this message `{"error":"Could not parse request body. Please check JSON format"}`

with the following request

```
import requests
import json

link = "https://api.3dsintegrator.com/v2/authenticate/browser"

data = {
    "pan":"",
    "amount":"89.95",
    "month":"01",
    "year":"27",
    "shipping": {
            "line1":"",
            "line2":"",
            "postCode":"78541",
            "city":"",
            "state":"",
            "country":""
            },
    "billing": {"line1":"","line2":"","city":"Edinburg","state":"","country":"840"},
    "cardHolderName":"",
    "messageCategory":"01",
    "browser": {"browserAcceptHeader":"application/json","browserJavaEnabled":"false","browserJavascriptEnabled":"true","browserLanguage":"en-US","browserColorDepth":"24","browserScreenWidth":"3200","browserScreenHeight":"1333","browserTZ":"420","browserUserAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0"},
    "challengeIndicator":"02",
    "challengeWindowSize": "01"
}
headers = {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-3DS-API-KEY": "",
    "X-3DS-SDK-VERSION": "",
    "Authorization": "Bearer ",
    "Content-Length": "731",
    "Origin": "https://winbigbonus.com",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Referer": "https://winbigbonus.com/",
    "TE": "Trailers",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0"
}

response = requests.post(link, headers=headers, data=data).text
print(response)
```

I removed most of the values for privacy reasons. But I believe my data object is already in json format so not sure why it is causing an error in the body and saying it's not able to parse it?

Comment: i wrapped your data between """{ all data same as your} """ , now convert it the way you need for the server method. print("Type of data",type(data))
json_str=json.dumps(data)
print("Type of json_str",type(json_str))
json_back=json.loads(data)
print("Type of json_back",type(json_back))
json_back["amount"] --->

Answer (score 0):

Your data value looks like a dictionary, not a JSON string. Try:

`response = requests.post(link, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data)).text`

Comment: it says AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'parse'

Comment: My fault; should use dumps. I just answered a question about javascript, and sometimes get the two mixed up.

Comment: hmm looks like the same error is coming up. So maybe it isn't the data object that is causing the error?

Comment: Inside of the post, are you not doing a json.loads() for what you get in, and then doing a json.dumps() for what you put out?

Comment: I tried adding json.dumps to the headers as well and I got an attribute error: "str" object has no attribute items

Comment: Don't add it to the headers; those are just fine the way they are. We're only worried about the data here, which is expected to be sent to and from your post method as JSON.

Comment: ok got it. Well after using json.dumps on the data variable, shouldn't it be a json string now? Which should be able to post correctly.

Comment: `json.dumps` takes an object and converts it to a JSON string. `json.loads` takes a JSON string and converts it to a usable object.

Comment: hmm any ideas on what to try? It's still giving me that error when I try posting the json.dumps(data)

Comment: What does your post method look like?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass amount value as Float not string for 3DS 2.1.0

```
"amount":89.95
```